# Enable cua-mode in term or ansi-term mode

Tags: ansi-term, term, cua-mode

While working with `term` or `ansi-term` in *term-line* mode, I am not able to use `cua-mode` bindings. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this from some time now, and never had the time/energy to look at it. But it seems it is pretty straightforward as it is described in [AnsiTermHints](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AnsiTermHints):

```
;; enable cua and transient mark modes in term-line-mode
(defadvice term-line-mode (after term-line-mode-fixes ())
  (set (make-local-variable 'cua-mode) t)
  (set (make-local-variable 'transient-mark-mode) t))
(ad-activate 'term-line-mode)

;; disable cua and transient mark modes in term-char-mode
(defadvice term-char-mode (after term-char-mode-fixes ())
  (set (make-local-variable 'cua-mode) nil)
  (set (make-local-variable 'transient-mark-mode) nil))
(ad-activate 'term-char-mode)
```

So `cua-mode` works in *term-line* mode and does not in *term-char* mode.

Comment: You can use `setq-local` if you're running Emacs 24.3+